# Backbone events and Twitter bootstrap popover

Tags: backbone.js, twitter-bootstrap

Insert backbone rendered view in twitter bootstrap popover like below. Problem is that when insert throught content option backbone events for that view don`t fire. I inserted view in div for test with $(selector).html attendanceShow.render().el  events work without problem. Thank you in advance

```
      attendance = new Attendance()
      attendance.url = "#{attendanceUrl}/#{attendanceId}" 
      attendance.fetch
        success: ->
          attendanceShow = new ExamAttendanceShow({model: attendance })
          currentTarget.popover
            html : true
            content: ->
              attendanceShow.render().el
```

Best regards,
Georgi.

Comment: have you tried running `delegateEvents()` after you add your view to the popover?

Comment: Yes, i tried but without success

Comment: I've been stuck on this same issue for hours.  Did you find a solution?  Thanks Mate!

Comment: I don`t found solution yet for this issue

Comment: Would like to know as well.

Comment: I need to see more code. How are you creating the 'currentTarget'? Is that something that is created dynamically? Maybe you need to wrap the target to $(currentTarget).popover. Tons of possibilities here..

Comment: @DennisRongo currentTarget is created by that way `currentTarget = $(event.currentTarget)` . Is is from event  `'click      .portion_set_attendance' : 'setPortionAttendance'`

Comment: Can you post what's on the render function of ExamAttendanceShow view? Are you calling the delegatEvents again? ie, render: function(){ this.delegateEvents();}

Comment: i`m tried to call only in ExamAttendanceShow this.delegateEvents(). But no success

Comment: Have you tried settings the View's events in the container View and see if they work? Meaning that in the view that creates the popover you put the events of the sub-view? (just for checking). Don't forget to replace the -> with =>.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, based on your code and your description you are only creating an instance of the popover but never showing it. I have a live demo working but not with CoffeeScript (I personally hate CoffeeScript), you can see the code below and at [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/erickrdch/kgGwv/).

data1.json

```
{"content": "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"}
```

index.html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <button class="btn" data-target="popover">Popover</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="row">
        <button class="btn" data-action="change-content">Change Content</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

main.js

```
var Main = Backbone.View.extend({
    model: null,
    item: null,
    popover: false,

    events: {
        'click .btn[data-target]': 'button_click',
        'click .btn[data-action="change-content"]': 'change_content'
    },

    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this);

        this.model = new PopoverModel();
        this.model.view = new PopoverContentView({model: this.model});

        this.item = this.$('.btn[data-target]');
        this.item.popover({
            html: true,
            content: this.model.view.render().el
        });
    },

    button_click: function(event) {
        if (!this.popover) {
            this.model.url = 'js/data1.json';
            this.model.fetch({
                success: this.model_fetched
            });
        } else {
            this.popover = false;
        }
    },

    model_fetched: function() {
        if (!this.popover) {
            this.item.popover('show');
        } else {
            this.item.popover('hide');
        }

        this.popover = !this.popover;
    },

    change_content: function(event) {
        this.model.set('content', 'Some random content... ' + parseInt(Math.random() * 10));
    }
});

var PopoverModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        content: ''
    }
});

var PopoverContentView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this);
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(_.template('<%= content %>', this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});


var main = new Main({
    el: '.container'
});
```

Comment: My problem is when i insert view inside popover i can`t attach event to that view. Thank you

Comment: Do you have a better example? Maybe I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue, to expand on Georgi's answer, please try this:

Place a button or a link in your popup (instead of the dynamic text you place) and handle an event, say click event on it.

Comment: want to confirm that it works. i had an old version of bootstrap (2.0.4) where the popover was not assigned to parent automatically. upgrading to 2.3.0 fixes it. sorry for noise.